# jdatechooser as parameter in mysql query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

what is the correct method so i can query this statement where the date from the jdatechooser will be my parameter

```
 DefaultTableModel model= (DefaultTableModel)DisplayRecieveTB.getModel();
        DisplayRecieveTB.revalidate();
        model.getDataVector().removeAllElements();

        try{

            String date = DateChooserRS.getDate().toString();

         stmt = conn.createStatement();
     stmt.executeQuery("SELECT *FROM supplyrecievable where recievedate = '"+date+"' ");
     rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
                    String r1 = rs.getString("itemname");
                    String r2 = rs.getString("itemgroup");
                    String r3 = rs.getString("itemcount");
                    String r4 = rs.getString("totalcost");
                    String r5 = rs.getString("itemcode");
                   model.addRow(new Object[] {r5,r1,r2,r3,r4}); 
                   DisplayRecieveTB.revalidate(); 

        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a `PreparedStatement`
2. Don't convert the `Date` value to `String`, the resulting values are likely to be incompatiable (and if the database column is anything other then a date or time stamp type, then you're doing it wrong)

For example...

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) DisplayRecieveTB.getModel();
DisplayRecieveTB.revalidate();
model.getDataVector().removeAllElements();

try {

    Date date = DateChooserRS.getDate();

    try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM supplyrecievable where recievedate = ?")) {
        // You can also use a java.sql.Timestamp if the column is of the correct type
        stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                String r1 = rs.getString("itemname");
                String r2 = rs.getString("itemgroup");
                String r3 = rs.getString("itemcount");
                String r4 = rs.getString("totalcost");
                String r5 = rs.getString("itemcode");
                model.addRow(new Object[]{r5, r1, r2, r3, r4});
                // This is pointless, as the model should notifty the table it needs to be updated
                //DisplayRecieveTB.revalidate();

            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}
```

This is assume the database column type is compatible with the `java.sql.Date` value

See [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details