# How can I save date from swing date chooser to derby tale with date field

Tags: java, swing, derby, jdatechooser

I have java swing date chooser and when I passed the  date  to derby table though prepared insert statement below i got  error message refusing the date date type ,in my  table i put date type is  date .
Below  the code the second field not accepted by the database   pst.setString(2,**dateChooser.getText()**);:

```
   public void DoSave()    {
           try{   
               String host1 = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//accountsdb";
               String uName1="accounts";
    String uPass1="accounts";
    con1=DriverManager.getConnection(host1,uName1 ,uPass1);
    String sql1="INSERT into journal                                             
   (journal_no,journal_date,journal_submain_no,journal_dr
   , journal_cr,journal_desc,journal_user,journal_docno) 
    values (    ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pst=con1.prepareStatement(sql1);
pst.setString(1,jTjournal_docno.getText().trim() );
pst.setString(2,dateChooser.getText());
 pst.setString(3,jTjournal_submain_no.getText().trim() );
 pst.setString(4,jTjournal_amount.getText() ); //Dr
pst.setString(5,jTjournal_amount.getText() );//Cr
pst.setString(6,jTjournal_desc.getText().trim() );
 pst.setString(7,Frmlogin.myname );
 pst.setString(8,jTjournal_docno.getText().trim() );
 pst.execute();
 rs.close();      
  doClear();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved ");
  new JFband().setVisible(true);
  this.dispose();
  }               
  catch (SQLException ex) {
      System.out.println(ex.getMessage())   ;      
}
   }
```

I have no idea how to send date to table through date chooser using prepaid statement above please help

Comment: Consider using `PreparedStatement#setDate`, you might need to convert the `java.util.Date` to a `java.sql.Date`, something like `new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime())` for example

Comment: And you probably should use `dateChooser.getDate()` or `getValue()` or whatever method will return the `Date` object

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180080/jdatechooser-as-parameter-in-mysql-query/30180124#30180124) for example

Comment: @ MadProgrammer Date Chooser looks it does has such properties as per my attempt now.

Comment: Which date chooser are you using, I know about 3

Comment: @ MadProgrammer I have no idea just i know i down load date chooser jar and added to my project but your are true because i try to use below got from web but not working with me  pst.setString(2,((JTextField)dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());

Comment: What package (`import ...`) does the `dateChooser` belong to?  How do you create an instance of the `dateChooser`? Perhaps it would be worthwhile actually reading the associated JavaDocs from the place you downloaded it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last I have got a solution seems the date chooser I'm using not familiar
 with my code ,now i was added jcalendar-1.3.3 jar library to my project
and replaced my old date choose with JDateChooser   and now the code working fine and i can
 insert records with date to my table as per my below code :

```
public void DoSave()    {
           try{   
               String host1 = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//accountsdb";
               String uName1="accounts";
  String uPass1="accounts";
   con1=DriverManager.getConnection(host1,uName1 ,uPass1);
   String sql1="INSERT into journal (journal_no,journal_date,journal_submain_no,journal_dr,journal_cr,journal_desc,journal_user,journal_docno) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

PreparedStatement pst=con1.prepareStatement(sql1);
pst.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(jLvoucher_no.getText().trim()) );
pst.setString(2,((JTextField)dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
 pst.setInt(3,Integer.parseInt(jTjournal_submain_no.getText().trim()) );
 pst.setInt(4,Integer.parseInt(jTjournal_amount.getText().trim()) ); //Dr
pst.setInt(5,Integer.parseInt(jTjournal_amount.getText().trim()) );//Cr
pst.setString(6,jTjournal_desc.getText().trim() );
 pst.setString(7,Frmlogin.myname );
 pst.setString(8,jTjournal_docno.getText().trim() );
 pst.execute();
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved");




  }               
  catch (SQLException ex) {
      System.out.println(ex.getMessage())   ;      
}
   }
```